# JQuery with HTML imagemap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".schedule_link").colorbox({width:"95%", innerHeight:344, iframe:true});
});
```

to attach the colorbox to a link ...

```
<a class='schedule_link' href="index.html">Schedules</a>
```

... but what is the syntax to attach it to an imagemap like this?

```
<map name="mymap">
   <area shape="rect" coords="496,500,729,523" href="??call JQuery??">
</map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colorbox actually operates on a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler that listens for clicks on elements with the [`cboxElement` class](http://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/blob/master/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js#L105).  Since [it gets the `href` off the element](http://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/blob/master/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js#L138) and [adds that class](http://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/blob/master/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js#L291), it's not `<a>` dependent, you can just do:

```
<map name="mymap" id="mymap">
   <area shape="rect" coords="496,500,729,523" href="myPage.html">
</map>
```

And your jQuery to bind these in one go, no need on a class for each `<area>`, for example:

```
$(function(){
  $("#mymap area").colorbox({width:"95%", innerHeight:344, iframe:true});
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, that worked. Do you think using individual id's might be better with imagemap because often have multiple areas?

Comment: @Mark - There's no need here, that one selector will find *all* `<area>` children of the `<map>` we're fetching by ID.

Comment: Cool - giving the area tags a class (casablanca's suggestion) has the same effect, but this answer, I guess, is more 'generic'. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can give your `<area>` tags a class just like the link:

```
<area class="something" shape="rect" coords="496,500,729,523" href="somepage.html">
```